# Getting data to a form c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to get data from a text file for employees date of birth, I have got all the other information in strings to show up on my form but not DOB. Here is the code where the streamreader is used to get the data.

```
 public bool Load(string employeesFile)
      {
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("employees.txt"))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //Splitting the data using |
                string[] temp = line.Split('|');

                //This is to populate an employees detials 
                Employee emp = new Employee()
                {
                    firstName = temp[0],
                    lastName = temp[1],
                    address = temp[2],
                    postCode = temp[3],
                    phoneNumber = temp[4],
                    //dateOfBirth = temp.ToString[5]
                };
```

Next is the code in the form to show the data in the form.

```
     public partial class Salaried_Employee_Details : Form
   {

    public Salaried_Employee_Details(Employee emp)
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        textBoxLastName.Text = emp.lastName;
        textBoxFirstName.Text = emp.firstName;
        textBoxAddress.Text = emp.address;
        textBoxPostCode.Text = emp.postCode;
        textBoxPhoneNumber.Text = emp.phoneNumber;
        dateTimeDateOfBirth.Text = emp.dateOfBirth.ToString();
```

the date of birth in the file is in this format 1995|5|22.

How do I get it to link from the text file to show in the form?

Comment: Don't post images of your code. This makes impossible for us to test it. Code is just text. Just add it to your question (IE Copy/Paste)

Comment: Add your Employee class and the string you are splitting to the question

Comment: Provide at least one line of file employees.txt. I think you need concat splits like `temp[5] + "/" + temp[6] + "/" + temp[7]`.

Comment: I have edited the question now and a line of the file is here:: Oakes|Wesley|13 Everywhere Street, EveryTown, UK|PR55 3TY|0114 2325413|2001|5|22|35000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are splitting the text with "|" and dates are in "1995|5|22" format, which means your dates will be splitted in three parts. If you get last three items (year,month,day) you can set a date like this;

```
int year = Convert.Int32(temp[5]);
int month = Convert.Int32(temp[6]);
int day = Convert.Int32(temp[7]);
//This is to populate an employees detials 
Employee emp = new Employee()
{
    firstName = temp[0],
    lastName = temp[1],
    address = temp[2],
    postCode = temp[3],
    phoneNumber = temp[4],
    dateOfBirth = new DateTime(year, month, day)
};
```

Comment: Hi so would this class have to be changed?  public DateTime dateOfBirth
        {
            get
            {
                return _dateOfBirth;
            }
            set
            {
                _dateOfBirth = value;
            }